# Count blank cells when using CountIFs

Tags: excel-formula, countif

I would like to include the count of blank cells in a column using countifs

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(Table5[CH Code & Room],$U67,Table5[Residency from],"<="&AA$6,Table5[Residency to],">="&AA$6,Table5[Residency to],"")>=1,1,0)
```

This formula works will all apart from counting blanks

Answer (score 0):

All the `-IFS` functions use AND logic so, if you want to use OR logic then you would have to sum multiple `-IFS` functions - a more concise approach is to use `SUMPRODUCT()`, e.g.

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT((Table5[CH Code & Room]=$U67)*(Table5[Residency from]<=AA$6)*((Table5[Residency to]>=AA$6)+(Table5[Residency to]=""))),1,0)
```